# git push patch to remote

Tags: git, git-push, git-patch

is it possible to push a formatted patch directly to remote server without even cloning the repo?
Something like:

```
git push http://git:mr/android.git master 0001-patch.patch
```

Comment: As far as i know you cant do it. in order to apply patch/archive/bundle you must clone the repo

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply a patch on a remote natively, through some kind of specif "push".

You would need to implement a listener which would detect a patch and apply it (like [applying patches from emails](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_patches_from_email), mentioned in "[Git Tip of the Week: Patches by Email](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html)").

But more generally, this isn't trivial to implement because of potential conflicts which might have to be resolved when applying the patch: this is much easier to do in a local cloned repo.

Comment: link is not valid anymore,  here you go: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_patches_from_email

Comment: @StefanKarlsson Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.